# No route matches [POST] "/sessions/user"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I just installed Devise on my app, I had previously done it by scratch like Michael Hartl tutorial.

Currently I can sign up and log out. But when I do log in it gives an error:

`No route matches [POST] "/sessions/user"`

it happens when I click on the sign in/log in button with or without the (correct) password.

My route file is:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}

resources :users do
  resources :bookings, only: [:show]
  end
resources :bookings
resources :sessions

# match '/signup',  to: 'devise/registrations#new', via: :get
# match '/signin',  to: 'devise/sessions#new', via: [:post, :get]
# match '/signout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', via: :delete
match '/admin',   to: 'admin#new', via:  :get
match "bookings/new", to: 'bookings#new', via: [:post, :get]

devise_scope :user do 
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
end
```

[EDIT]

My form is the default from devise:

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>
  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
    <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>
  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Currently I don't have any code on Session Controller nor Helper like in the Michael Hartl tutorial

My rake routes regarding Sessions are as follows:

```
            sessions GET      /sessions(.:format)                    sessions#index
                     POST     /sessions(.:format)                    sessions#create
         new_session GET      /sessions/new(.:format)                sessions#new
        edit_session GET      /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)           sessions#edit
             session GET      /sessions/:id(.:format)                sessions#show
                     PATCH    /sessions/:id(.:format)                sessions#update
                     PUT      /sessions/:id(.:format)                sessions#update
                     DELETE   /sessions/:id(.:format)                sessions#destroy
```

[SOLVED]

I updated the routes file

```
  devise_scope :user do 
    root to: 'static_pages#home'
    match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
  end
```

Comment: can I see your form and corresponding controller method?

Comment: I just edited the file to include the form, but it's the devise default form. My Session Controller currently doesn't have any code

Comment: @TiagoOrnelasVieira I am glad you were able to solve your problem. If you could either accept the solution that gave you the answer or submit the answer that you found on your own and give it the check it would help those viewing your question. If you don't really know how to explain why your solution worked then ask us and maybe someone will give an explanation of why your solution fixed your problem. Once you or someone has answered the question completely please give it the check mark so this will be closed and so Stack Overflow will be kept tidy and concise. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following lines in the routes file

```
post ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Also remove 
`match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'` ->causes a conflict in later versions

Comment: This may have solved the problem but can you explain what exactly it down. I think it does the same thing as match. I know in rails 4.0.0+ you can't use `match` without `via: [:get, :post]`, `via: :all` or `via: ` whatever but other than that, I don't see how this helps. Also it is doing this for every controller right? So could this cause problems later?

Comment: I really don't know why match does not work for me, but when I replaced it in the routes file with get and post definitions separately it seemed to work. This may not be the exact soloution, it may cause problems later on (none that I have come across)but it kind of helps if you manually write route definitions when the rake route conflict page pops up.

Answer (score 7):

A possible solution I came up is:

```
 devise_scope :user do 
    root to: 'static_pages#home'
    match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
  end
```

Comment: I've just spend ages trying to resolve the same problem as this question. This solution saved me from having to rename an existing model called 'session' to something else, which is what seemed like the only way to fix it properly... thankfully it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

In the `sessions/new` view, check the link you've included in the sign-in button.  It's possible you have `user` instead of `:user` or a similar typo that goes to the wrong path. Also check the output of `$ rake routes` - is the sign-in button pointing to a path that exists?  Have you made some named routes in `routes.rb`?

In the Hartl tutorial, if you've followed the default, when you log in it should be directing you from

`sessions#new` to `users#show` (the `user_path`)

Comment: I fix it. I match the sessions/user route with the devise/sessions#create via post