# No route matches [POST] "/sessions/user" with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, routes

When i try to log in using devise on my rails app, I get the following error.

> No route matches [POST] "/sessions/user"

I have tried other solutions that I have found here but they don't seem to work.

My `routes.rb` has the following in the file.

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :non_availabilities
  resources :sessions
  resources :programs
  resources :activities
  resources :locations
  resources :employees
  resources :expertises
  resources :emp_classifications
  resources :educations
  get 'dashboard/index'
  root 'dashboard#index'
end.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: can you remove `resources :sessions` from your routes.

Comment: Sessions is actually the name of one of my models so I need that. Would that cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this line to your routes

```
match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
```

Comment: Hi Nourza, I inputted the code you gave me and I got the following error.                                                              ** Could not find devise mapping for path "/sessions/user". This may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]**

Comment: any other ideas of how to fix my problem?

Comment: Try this   devise_scope :user do 
    
    match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
  end

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same situation (my app has a `Session` model and `SessionsController` too). [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392033/no-route-matches-post-sessions-user/21024350#21024350) worked for me, with a tiny modification. The code below was added to `config/routes.rb`:

```rb
devise_scope :user do
  match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
end
```